# order of group element provided coset number

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to do an exercise but I am confused at this question. Isn't the order of $a$ just $3$.

I am trying to use Lagrange Theorem but to no avail since I have no clue what $G$ is.

[image: Order Group Question]

Comment: Well, at least $\;30\;$ , uh?

Comment: @DonAntonia How did you get that ? I understand that 3 divides the order of the factor group and order of G divides 10 thus 30 is number of elements in G at least but how does that pertain to order of a ?

Comment: So, offhand, you know that $a^3H = H$, not that the order of $a$ is $3$.

Comment: Well we know that $|G|$ must be at least 30, since $|G/H| = |G|/|H|$. Since $aH$ has an order of 3, it must be true that $|G/H|$ is a multiple of 3.

Comment: @DonAntonio - what about $a =(1,0)\in {\mathbb Z/3}\times {\mathbb Z/10}$?

Comment: @DonAntonio It must **divide** $30$, not be at least $30$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Doesn't peterag example show it can be three ?

Comment: @Nameless - it can have order $3$ - it doesn't have to, though. Try $a=(1,1)$ in the above example.

Comment: @peterag Hmmm... yeah the order of that is 30. I am thinking that the order can be 3, 6, 15, 30 ?

Comment: Right - you don't need to know much about $G$ itself...  As Ted wrote $a^3\in H$, so the order of $a^3$ divides $10$. Is it clear that $3$ divides the order of $a$?

Comment: @peterag why does 3 divide order of $a$ ? 3 divides order of the factor group G/H.

Comment: Let $m$ be the order of $a$.Then $(aH)^{m} = a^{m}H = H$. It follows that $3|m$ so that $m = 3k$.

Comment: You don't need to know $G$ or $G/H$; only that the image of $a$ in $G/H$ is of order $3$. Do you understand?

Comment: @en, I meant that at least the number $\;30\;$ is one possibility, *not* that $\;30\;$ is the minimal such possibility...but I understand the misunderstanding. :)

Comment: @peterag Read my above comment. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio -aah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|a|$ clearly divides $30$, for we have:

$a^{30} = (a^3)^{10} = h^{10}$ for some $h \in H$, and by Lagrange, $h^{10} = e$ (since $\langle h\rangle$ is a subgroup of $H$ and its order, which *is* $|h|$,
 must divide $10$).

On, the other hand, if $|a| = k$, then $a^k = e \in H$, and since $aH$ has order $3$, we must have $3 \mid k$ (for otherwise, $aH = H$, or $a^2H = H$, contradiction).

The possibilities are thus:

$3,6,15,30$.

Letting $G = \Bbb Z_{30}$ and $H = \langle 3\rangle$ (which has order $10$), we see that $1+H$ and $2+H$ both have order $3$ in $G/H$, and:

$10 \in 1+H$ has order $3$ in $G$.

$5 \in 2+H$ has order $6$ in $G$.

$2 \in 2+H$ has order $15$ in $G$, and

$1 \in 1+H$ has order $30$ in $G$, which settles the question.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a subgroup $K\subseteq G/H$ generated by $aH$. It follows that $K\simeq G'/H$ for some subgroup $H\subseteq G'\subseteq G$ such that $a\in G'$. Since $|G'/H|=3$ and $|H|=10$ then it follows (by Lagrange's theorem) that $|G'|=30$. And since $a\in G'$ then $|a|$ divides $30$.

Are all divisors of $30$ possible? If you consider $G'=\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ and $H=0\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ then $3, 6, 15, 30$ are clearly possible values of $|a|$. Obviously $1$ is not possible.

What about $2, 5$? (thanks to @DavidWheeler) Of course if $|a|=2$ or $|a|=5$ then $K$ being the image of $\langle a\rangle$ would have to be of order $1,2$ or $5$. But $|K|=3$. Contradiction.

Comment: 2 is not possible, for if so, $aH$ could not have order 3. 5 is likewise not possible for it leads to $H = a^3H = a^5H \implies a^2 \in H$.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on David W's answer.

Write $\langle a\rangle$ for the cyclic subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$.

One has a surjective homomorphism $\pi$

$$ \left< a \right> \to \langle a\rangle H / H,$$
defined by $\pi\colon a^k\mapsto a^k H$. This is a homomorphism, as $H$ is normal.

The kernel $K$ of $\pi$ is $\langle a\rangle \cap H$. By hypothesis the image of $\pi$ has cardinality $3$. Therefore $\#\langle a \rangle = 3 \ \cdot \#K$. Now, the only possibilities for the cardinality of $K$  are $1,2,5, 10$, as $K$ is a subgroup of $H$. So the only possibilities for the order of $a$ are $3, 6, 15, 30$. By explicit construction (as in the comments, or in David's answer), we see all of these occur.